# integral of Q-function and modified bessel function

Tags: special-functions, closed-form

the integral is given in this link

http://www.mediafire.com/view/3mpjo9j3stsddz1/Untitled.png

where Q(t) is the gaussian error function, I_v(.) is the modified bessel function, anything else is constant and real